# qmake match linux and mac separatly

Tags: linux, macos, qt, qt4

I'm creating a .pro file for both Mac and Linux platform.

I will link the qca framework on Mac, and libqca on Linux

```
mac {
    ICON = mac.icns
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/qca/2.1.0/include/
    LIBS += -F/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/qca/2.1.0/lib -framework qca
}

unix {
    LIBS += -lqca
}
```

However, the unix part matches both mac and linux, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the colon `:` to take a product (logical-and) of multiple conditions, some of which may be negated:

```
unix:!mac {
  ...
}
```